# How to permanently disable audio and camera in openmeetings room?

Tags: openmeetings

I am using Apache Openmeetings. Since I don't use audio and Camera features on a particular room, i would like to permanently disable the camera/audio popup when Guests login to the meeting room.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several options available out-of the box:

1. Use room of type "presentation" and make it "Moderated". This way Audio/Video popup will not be automatically displayed, only moderators will have rights to share their Camera/Microphone
2. You can also made room "Audio only". This way there will be no video options available
3. Additionally you can modify `webapps/openmeetings/css/custom.css` and hide 'Audio/Video setup', 'Share Camera' and 'Share microphone' UI icons